# Templates and virtual function that has *at least* certain arguments

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I understand that virtual functions cannot be templated, but is there a way that derived classes implement a generic function and the virtual function requires sucha generic function to have *at least* certain arguments? I provide two examples, the first of which is the simplified example and the second of which is a more realistic motivation for what I want to do (I am a C++ beginner, so I could be way off in my thinking).

Simplified:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
  template<class T>
  virtual T foo(T a, T b, ...) = 0;
};

class DerivedSimple : public Base
{
public:
  // Meets the minimum argument requirements in the Base class
  template<class T>
  T foo(T a, T b) override;
};

class DerivedExtended : public Base
{
public:
  // Has the minimum required args AND an arg specific to this class
  template<class T>
  T foo(T a, T b, int some_special_argument) override;
};
```

Extended:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

class SmootherBase
{
public:
    /**
     * @brief Derived types must implement a `smooth` function that smooths `Au = b`.
     * 
     */
    template <class T>
    virtual Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1> smooth (
        const Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>& A,  // <--|
        const Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>& u0,//    |
        const Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>& b, //    | must have these args
        const size_t niters,              // <--|
        ...                               // optional args for different smoother
    ) = 0;
};

class SuccessiveOverRelaxation : public SmootherBase
{
private:
public:
    template <class T>
    Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1> smooth (
        const Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>& A,  // <--|
        const Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>& b, //    | The required arguments
        const Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>& u0,//    |
        const size_t niters,              // <--|
        const float omega                 // An argument specific to this smoother
    ) override;
};

class Jacobi : public SmootherBase 
{
private:
public:
    template <class T>
    Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1> smooth (
        const Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>& A,  // <--|
        const Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>& u0,//    |
        const Eigen::Matrix<T, -1, 1>& b, //    | The required arguments
        const size_t niters,              // <--|
    ) override;
};
```

Comment: You can't haver a virtual function template.  full stop.  One thing you could do is have a `std::variant` of the different types you want to support and then you can use the visitor pattern to apply the correct thing to do based on the type that is actually being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override a function that has a different signature. If you're sending these extra arguments to the class purely to affect its behavior (*e.g.* configuration options), then consider changing your approach so that you provide them in the constructor and use them in `foo()`.

As you already mentioned, you cannot template virtual functions. So it's odd that you did exactly that in your examples.

Here's the approach I describe above:

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
public:
  virtual T foo(T a, T b) = 0;
};

template<class T>
class DerivedSimple : public Base<T>
{
public:
  T foo(T a, T b) override;
};

template<class T>
class DerivedExtended : public Base<T>
{
public:
  DerivedExtended(int some_special_argument)
    : some_special_argument(some_special_argument)
  {}

  T foo(T a, T b) override;

protected:
  int some_special_argument;
};
```

Comment: Regarding Ted's now-deleted comment about it being possible to override functions with variadic arguments, I agree that's not a good idea! It's a little unclear what driver code is supposed to be calling `foo()`, but it looks like the intention is to encapsulate some kind of I/O kernel for filtering. If that's being called with variadic inputs then my gut screams "XY Problem".

Comment: The extended code has the desired example. The only addition would be a main function that instantiates each of the smoothers and then calls something like `smooth(A, u0, b)` and `smooth(A, u0, b, omega` respectively. But I think using the class data members as config is a fair solution.