# Undefined reference to implementation of function template of class template

Tags: c++, templates, cmake

I have the follow cmake project structure:

```
|projectdir
|
|
|-- include/modern/
|           |
|           |_ lib.hpp
|
|-- src/
|   |
|   |_ CMakeLists.txt
|   |
|   |_ lib.cpp
|   
|-- test/
|   |
|   |_ CMakeLists.txt
|   |
|   |_ testlib.cpp
|
|-- CMakeLists.txt
```

and whenever I attempt to build from the `projectdir` by running `cmake --build build`, I
get the following error:

[image]

The error I think comes from the class template and constructor declaration in `lib.hpp` and the constructor template implementation in `lib.cpp` not being recognized, but how can I fix this? The contents of all files are given below, assume that I need to keep the class template and the function template (see my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78117068/templates-and-virtual-function-that-has-at-least-certain-arguments) question for the motivation for this structure).

```cpp
// include/modern/lib.hpp
#pragma once

template <class T>
class Rectangle {
private:
    int x {1};
    int y {1};
public:
    Rectangle();
    Rectangle(int x_, int y_);
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/CMakeLists.txt
set(HEADER_LIST "${ModernCMakeExample_SOURCE_DIR}/include/modern/lib.hpp")
add_library(modern_library lib.cpp ${HEADER_LIST})
target_include_directories(modern_library PUBLIC ../include)
target_compile_features(modern_library PUBLIC cxx_std_17)


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// src/lib.cpp
#include <modern/lib.hpp>

template <class T>
Rectangle<T>::Rectangle() {}

template<class T>
Rectangle<T>::Rectangle(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("x and y must be positive real");
    }
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test/CMakeLists.txt
# Testing library
FetchContent_Declare(
  catch
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
  GIT_TAG v2.13.6)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(catch)
# Adds Catch2::Catch2

add_executable(testlib testlib.cpp)
target_compile_features(testlib PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(testlib PRIVATE modern_library Catch2::Catch2)
add_test(NAME testlibtest COMMAND testlib) # Command can be a target


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test/testlib.cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
#include <modern/lib.hpp>

TEST_CASE( "Quick check", "[main]" ) {
    Rectangle<double> r1;
    Rectangle<double> r2(2, 2);
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// projectdir/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14...3.28)
project(
  ModernCMakeExample
  VERSION 0.1
  DESCRIPTION "An example project with CMake"
  LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

Note that my project structure is based on the [modern-cmake extended code sample](https://gitlab.com/CLIUtils/modern-cmake/tree/master/examples/extended-project).

Comment: All template code must be placed in header files, delete lib.cpp.